# Web Wallet requirements

Tags: wallets, security

I thinking about make a web wallet. I want to know what requirements it has to pass to be considered as a safe and trust by the community.

I thought about adding code integrity checks to compare code base with GitHub branch, possibility to install the app on your device (PWA will allow me to do that) and open sourcing.

I believe providing safe solutions for basic things is one of the most important things to be done to increase adoption of Stellar technologies

Comment: We have around 20 different wallets and none of them are perfect. What is it do you have in mind that haven't been done before? Maybe it's better to contribute to existing wallet instead and make it better?

Comment: I thought about adding cold transaction feature, universal UI accessible from mobile and desktop devices, and a module for playing with test network, creating accounts, testing different transaction on it, maybe some interactive tutorials.

Comment: So my point is - before you can get to this interesting stuff - you will spend half a year developing basic functionality. Maybe choose another project -  and help improve it with your ideas/ features

Answer (score 5):

Something you could do is to [host the site directly on github pages](https://pages.github.com/) so users can inspect the code as well as clone the wallet and run it locally.

A project that has implemented this is Ark whose [official web wallet](https://arkecosystem.github.io/ark-lite-wallet/app/) is hosted on github.

Of course, someone could still hack into your github account and make a malicious commit that isn't caught fast enough by the community, so this method is not completely fool-proof.